# How to give object a name

Tags: php

When I do the following:

```
$arUserStuff =  array ('name' => 'username', 'email' => 'test@test.com');

$object = (object) $arUserStuff;

print_r($object);
```

The print function returns me the following:

```
stdClass Object ( [name] => username [email] => test@test.com )
```

How can I change std class object in let's say's User Object?

Answer (score 6):

Create that class, then create an object of it:

```
class User {
    public $name, $email; // public for this example, or set these by constructor

    public function __construct( array $fields) {
        foreach( $fields as $field => $value) 
            $this->$field = $value;
    }
}

$object = new User;
$object->name = 'username';
$object->email = 'test@test.com';
```

Or, you can do:

```
$arUserStuff =  array ('name' => 'username', 'email' => 'test@test.com');
$object = new User( $arUserStuff);
```

Now, from `print_r( $object);`, you'll get something like this:

```
User Object ( [name] => username [email] => test@test.com )
```

Comment: You should add a constructor (maybe a factory constructor) that takes an array, to be more like what the OP was doing

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but you could be creating fields that you didn't intend to by copying all keys from the array.

Comment: Yes I'm aware - It's a simple example to a simple question.

Answer (score 1):

actually to do what you want, you should make it like:

```
$arUserStuff =  new ArrayObject(
  array (
    'name' => 'username', 'email' => 'test@test.com'
  )
);
```

to change the class name you need to create a new class. 
It's a rather complex process but you can learn about it here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score -1):

Here's a generic function that converts an array into any type of object, assuming the fields are public

```
class User { public $name, $email; }

class Dog { public $name, $breed; }

function objFromArray($className, $arr) {
       $obj = new $className;
       foreach(array_keys(get_class_vars($className)) as $key) {
           if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
               $obj->$key = $arr[$key];
           }           
       }
       return $obj;
}

print_r(objFromArray('User', 
    array ('name' => 'username', 'email' => 'test@test.com')));    
echo "<br/>";
print_r(objFromArray('Dog', 
    array ('name' => 'Bailey', 'breed' => 'Poodle')));
```

**Output**

```
User Object ( [name] => username [email] => test@test.com )
Dog Object ( [name] => Bailey [breed] => Poodle )
```

I wanted to make a trait out of it but don't have PHP 5.4 installed to test it. This wouldn't require the fields to be public

```
trait ConvertibleFromArray {
    public static function fromArray($arr) {
        var $cls = get_called_class();
        var $obj = new $cls;
        foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
            if (property_exists($obj, $arr)) {
               $obj->$key = $value;
            }
        }        
        return $obj;
    }
}    
class User {
    use ConvertibleFromArray;
    public $name, $email;
}    
class Dog {
    use ConvertibleFromArray;
    public $name, $breed;
}
print_r(User::fromArray(array ('name' => 'username', 'email' => 'test@test.com')));
print_r(Dog::fromArray(array('name' => 'Bailey', 'breed' => 'Poodle')));
```

?>